I need to use an associated constant in an associated type in Rust
I want to create a trait to define a constant LEN and an array of length LEN as the output type of a trait function, but I am not allowed to:
trait TransformIntoArray {
    const LEN: usize;
    fn transform_into_array(&self) -> [f64; Self::LEN];
    fn array_description(&self) -> [&'static str; Self::LEN];
}

this does not work. I want to make both return-types of the two function have the same length that is defined in the trait implementation. But that's not possible here.
Is there another solution I don't see?

The other answers do a good job working around the limitations of stable Rust. On nightly Rust, there is an feature that allows your original code to compile:
#![allow(incomplete_features)]
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

trait TransformIntoArray {
   const LEN: usize;
   fn transform_into_array(&self) -> [f64; Self::LEN];
   fn array_description(&self) -> [&'static str; Self::LEN];
}

The feature is deemed incomplete, but is complete enough for the above to work. Only use this as a last resort, if the stable workarounds don't work.

thank you! THAT is what I was looking for. I would rather like to avoid having a generic trait, because i have to use the trait in more complicated structs. But having to use nightly and allow unstable features might make me reconsider. I will try around a little. Thank you very much!

You could use the constant as generic parameter:
trait TransformIntoArray<const LEN: usize> {
    fn transform_into_array(&self) -> [f64; LEN];
    fn array_description(&self) -> [&'static str; LEN];
}


Thank you for this answer. This is the thing I came up, where I couldn't remove the generic parameter. I might have to use it though, if everything else fails eventually.Thank you!
